# How to shorten a bit complex long query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

see the image. i am trying to generate full result with sql. now i am generating UI with lots of front end code.
[image]

one guy gave me the whole sql which giving me the right output by SQL. here is the full sql.

```
DECLARE @FirstOfMonth DATE={ts'2011-02-01 00:00:00'};

WITH DateBorders AS
(
    SELECT @FirstOfMonth AS FirstOfMonth
          ,DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FirstOfMonth)) AS LastOfMonth 
)
,ThirtyOneNumbers(N) AS
(
        SELECT N FROM(VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                            ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                            ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
                            ,(31))t(N)
)
,RunningDates AS
(
    SELECT N AS DayNumber
          ,DATEADD(DAY,N-1,DateBorders.FirstOfMonth) DayDate
    FROM ThirtyOneNumbers,DateBorders
    WHERE ThirtyOneNumbers.N<=DATEDIFF(DAY,DateBorders.FirstOfMonth,DateBorders.LastOfMonth) + 1
)
,RunningDatesExt AS
(
    SELECT RunningDates.*
          ,wd.WeekDayInx
    FROM RunningDates
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DayDate)) AS wd(WeekDayInx)
)
,HourSheetSum AS
(
    SELECT hs.SpecialistID
          ,hs.EntryDate
          ,SUM(hs.HoursData) AS SumHoursData
    FROM HourSheet AS hs
    GROUP BY hs.SpecialistID,hs.EntryDate
)
,DataToPivot AS
(
    SELECT s.SpecialistID,
           s.Name, 
           rde.DayNumber,

           CASE WHEN h.SumHoursData IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN rde.WeekDayInx IN(6,7) THEN 'S'
                                                  ELSE '8.00'  
                                             END
                ELSE CAST(h.SumHoursData AS VARCHAR(100)) END AS HoursData

    FROM RunningDatesExt AS rde
         CROSS JOIN Specialists AS s
         LEFT JOIN HourSheetSum AS h ON h.SpecialistID=s.SpecialistID AND rde.DayDate=h.EntryDate
)
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   MIN(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

now issue is the above sql is working fine but become very big. how can i shorten it.

in this CTE value is hard coded

```
ThirtyOneNumbers(N) AS
(
        SELECT N FROM(VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                            ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                            ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
                            ,(31))t(N)
)
```

but my below sql return days in month.....it could be 31 or 30 or 28 etc

```
DECLARE @Days AS INT
DECLARE @DateInput AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @DateInput = '01/01/2011'

SELECT @Days = DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@DateInput),0)))
PRINT @Days

;WITH TotalDaysInMoth(MonthNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber+1 
    FROM TotalDaysInMoth
    WHERE MonthNumber < @Days
)

select * from TotalDaysInMoth;
```

now my question is how can i make this area dynamic instead of hard coded value

```
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   MIN(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

i am looking for suggestion. **in FOR DayNumber IN (1,2,3......31) is hard coded which i do not want**. i want it should show  no of days in month. without making this area dynamic how can i achieve my goal and make shorter.

looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: You should not use a recursive for counting like that. It is just like a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/ You should just use a numbers or tally table instead of either of those approaches. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: One of very ineffective way to achieve this: can be `WITH .. SELECT * INTO #temp...` then `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN` based on month unwanted columns and `SELECT * FROM #temp`. No dynamic-sql as you wanted.

Comment: @Mou (or Thomas???). Please look at my comment in the last thread. It is much easier to make some columns of your DataGridView invisible than to fiddle around with a "shorter" query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace you first FOUR CTE(s) with one by using the following:

```
DECLARE @FirstOfMonth DATE={ts'2011-02-01 00:00:00'};



 SELECT DAY(DayNumber) AS DayNumber
       ,CAST(DayNumber AS Date) DayDate
       ,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DayNumber) AS WeekDayIndx
FROM(
      SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN YEAR(@FirstOfMonth) % 4 = 0 THEN 366 ELSE 365 END) 
           DATEADD(DAY 
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
                 , CAST(YEAR(@FirstOfMonth) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' )  DayNumber
      From master..spt_values
     )x
WHERE DayNumber > DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@FirstOfMonth),0))
 AND  DayNumber < DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@FirstOfMonth)+1,0))
```

Comment: see this url http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/03/03/sql-server-various-leap-year-logics/ they use bit different logic to calculate leap year but u used different. so your one will return right result all the time ?

Comment: people use this logic for leap year detection `CASE WHEN (@YEAR % 4 = 0 AND @YEAR % 100 <> 0) OR @YEAR % 400 = 0 THEN 'LEAP YEAR'..`

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want it to be dynamic? That doesn't shorten it, it makes it a lot more complex. In SQL you're supposed to have a fixed number of columns in your select / result set, not something that changes depending on the date given as parameter.

The only way to make that pivot dynamic is to create dynamic SQL that contains the actual number of days for that month -- and that means creating all that SQL in a varchar variable.

Also, your way of creating the 31 days using the recursive CTE is also pointless, because RunningDates already had that limit (N<=DATEDIFF(DAY,DateBorders.FirstOfMonth,DateBorders.LastOfMonth) + 1)

Edit: Forgot to mention, the displaying or hiding columns 29 - 31 should be done in the GUI, or to be more precise, you shouldn't even have the pivot, you should return the data in rows and make the transpose into columns in the client side.

Comment: The key thing here is your proc should really always return data that conforms to some contract. IE the same number of columns with the same names, (and ideally although not as much) in the same order.